# How to build the function in typescript in case of checkbox that by default to be not checked?

Tags: angular, typescript

So I need to create this function:

```
  buildForm(): void {

    console.log('build form');
    this.notificationForm = this.fb.group({
      appCreated: [],
      appSubmittedReview: [],
      appCancelReview: [],
      appRequestForDeletion: [],
      appDisable: [],
      appReEnable: [],
      appReviewPublished: [],
      appReviewApproved: [],
      appReviewDeleted: [],

    });
  }
```

All the fields are a checkbox and I want that by default those to be not checked, can anyone help me with creating this `buildForm`.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field's status depend on the default value of FormBuilder, try this:

```
  this.notificationForm = this.fb.group({
      appCreated: [true],
      appSubmittedReview: [],
      appCancelReview: [],
      appRequestForDeletion: [],
      appDisable: [true],
      appReEnable: [],
      appReviewPublished: [],
    });
```

in HTML

```
   <form [formGroup]="notificationForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
         appCreated:  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="appCreated" >
         appSubmittedReview:  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="appSubmittedReview" >
         appCancelReview:  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="appCancelReview" >
         appRequestForDeletion:  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="appRequestForDeletion" >
         appDisable:  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="appDisable" >
         appReEnable:  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="appReEnable" > 
      </form>
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iupovx)

Comment: I want them to be false if nothing comes from the backend 
 if I selected sth I get what I have set in build form and not the real values, can you help with that

Comment: try to add a submit button to check what i mean in html

Answer (score 1):

use `false` as a default value

```
buildForm(): void {

    console.log('build form');
    this.notificationForm = this.fb.group({
      appCreated: false,
      appSubmittedReview: false,
      appCancelReview: false,
      appRequestForDeletion: false,
      appDisable: false,
      appReEnable: false,
      appReviewPublished: false,
      appReviewApproved: false,
      appReviewDeleted: false,

    });
}
```

Comment: will this not influenced if in API for example i get  some of them true ??